# Leaky soda keg - has beer in it

Tags: kegging, corny-keg

I have a keg about 1/4 full of Black IPA (delicious) and I have been hooking up co2 when I want a pint of it, to save on co2 because there is a noticeable leak in the lid.

I picked up some keg lube the other day and my question is, is it al right if I pop the lid off and lube the o-ring (the o-ring looks in great condition) up and snap the lid back in place or will that ruin the beer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it will not. A concern you might have if the keg was full would be the sudden foaming as you depressurize, which might overflow the keg. But at 1/4 full, no problem.

If you're concerned about O₂, don't be. You'll have a keg full of heavy CO₂, and will only open the lid for a few moments, not enough time for any substantial O₂ to mix in.  If you're concerned, vent the headspace a couple/few times after you re-seal and re-pressurize.

Also, some keg lids, in my experience, seal better in one orientation vs. the opposite one. Perhaps just rotate the lid 180° and see if it seals better that way, without lube, to start off.

Comment: thanks, just doing my homework before doing that, appreciate the advice.

Comment: UPDATE: applied keg lube and that did the trick, after a couple days, the beer was back to new with the proper carbonation and it was good until I kicked it a couple weeks later.